# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+1)^\alpha}$, when $0 < \alpha < 2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I've been working on this integral for ages and I can't seem to figure it out. I can coax Mathematica to solve it for special values of $\alpha$ (integers and tidy fractions), and those special cases tend to include lots of generalized hypergeometric functions, which makes me think the general form must be pretty wild. I've pored over Gradshteyn & Ryzhik, trying to do pattern matching on this integral and various substitutions of it, with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you come across this integral? Some context would be nice

Comment: Oerlapping the other comment: do you have any reason to believe that it _has_ a closed form?

Comment: This integral came up when trying to compute the partition function of a PDF I'm playing with. I have no reason to believe that it has a closed form, except that 1) it's finite and smooth in the range that I care about, and 2) it has a closed form for special cases of $\alpha$. I'd actually be thrilled to learn that it doesn't have a closed form, as it would mean I have to focus on approximations. Is there a way to prove that it does or doesn't have a closed form?